# Already included class

Tags: php, class

Is it possible to make my class file be already included in all files of a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is also `auto_prepend_file` configuration option
so, you can add an .htaccess file (in case you're running PHP as Apache module)  to that folder with following line:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/that/file
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at:

[Autoloading Classes Using __autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (offical Docs)

**Example:**

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also automatically prepend files using [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) - set the path in php.ini, httpd.conf or an .htaccess file:

```
Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require() function, so include_path is used.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using class autoloading: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Very useful

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the already mentioned [autoloading of classes](http://php.net/language.oop5.autoload) you could also specify a file with [*auto_prepend_file*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in a .htaccess file that is loaded before:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file foo.php
```

With this the file *foo.php* is loaded whenever a PHP file in that directory or a subdirectory is requested.